# How to filter / replace values >0 conditional on dimension in 3D np array?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, dimension

I have a 3D numpy array of size `(260,311,260)` and I want to replace all value greater than 0 in the first dimension with 0 (i.e. keeping the dimensions). This would mean setting half of the 'cube' to 0.

I've tried so far

```
np.where(A[A>0,:,:],1,0)
```

and

```
A_x = A.T[(A[0]>0).any(axis=0).T].T
```

and also with a boolean mask

```
bool_mask = (A> 0)
A[bool_mask == True]
```

But nothing worked so far.
Obviously I could write a loop but isn't there a more elegant way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: what do you mean by 'replace all values greater than 0 in the **first dimension** with 0'?